# How to download data from an excel file from webserver

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to get data from excel file which is located on internet web server.
Now my code looks like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application

    ' open the webpage here
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("localhost/test/test.xlsx")

    Range("$A$1").Value = oWB
End Sub
```

But it does not work. How can I solve it ?

Comment: You're trying to place a workbook object in a cell?

Comment: so how should I do it correct ?

Comment: from which worksheet and which cell are you trying to get the value in cell "A1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
Sub DownloadFileWithVBA()

Dim myURL As String
'Right-click on the link named 'Sample Address File'
'Click 'Copy Link Location'
'Paste the link below
myURL = "http://databases.about.com/library/samples/address.xls"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\address.xls")
    oStream.Close

End Sub
```

This should help you too....

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub pMain()
  Dim sURL As String
  Dim sDestination As String
  Dim bSuccess As Boolean
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim strSavePath As String
  Dim URL As String, ext As String
  Dim buf, ret As Long

  'Change to suit
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  With ws
    For lRow = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      sURL = .Cells(lRow, "A")
      sDestination = .Cells(lRow, "B")

      buf = Split(sURL, ".")
      ext = buf(UBound(buf))

        pos = InStrRev(sURL, "/", -1)
        file = Mid(sURL, pos + 1, 99)
        strSavePath = sDestination & file
        ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, sURL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
            If ret = 0 Then
                .Cells(lRow, "C") = "File download successfully!"
            Else
                .Cells(lRow, "C") = "Couldn't download the file!"
            End If

      DoEvents
    Next lRow
  End With
End Sub
```

In the second script, your setup should be like this (image).

[image]